# Android Studio Component Installation Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, sdk, mobile-development

It is my first time learning how to use android studio and I get this Installation error.
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5yzy.png)
components are not installed.

I have tried installing it manually and have the files extracted on google_apis but it is not working, I have also tried deleting the folders wherein the installation takes place but no luck for me, can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried downloading the files manually using the download link on the logs shown and I moved the downloaded zip files to the C:\Users(NameOfUser)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.temp then it worked!